# Cakephp Missing Controller

Tags: cakephp

When I tried to run my website. It always shown me this error.

Missing Controller

Error: RealestateController could not be found.

Error: Create the class RealestateController below in file: app\controllers\realestate_controller.php

I don't have such controller yet, What should I do ?

Comment: Does the URL for your site end with /realestate?

Comment: Check `APP/config/routes.php` for any trace of `realestate`

Answer (score 0):

Just create a file in your controllers folder as such:

Name the file `realestate_controller.php`

And in this file add

```
<?php
class RealestateController extends AppController{
    //If you want you can add
    public function index(){
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks,